# Different between <span> and <p>

Tags: html

When I use code:

```
<span>asdf<div>indiv</div>
```

then browser change to `<span>asdf<div>indiv</div></span>`
replace span by p:

```
<p>asdf<div>indiv</div>
```

then browser change to

```
<p>asdf</p><div>indiv</div>
```

So what is the rule to change html struct.

Comment: half of these are invalid since they miss closing tags. the browser is closing them for you

Comment: The "rule" is likely to differ between browsers since they're all just trying to correct invalid markup.  When the markup is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @David This is no longer true in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that a `span` tag has to have a closing tag to be correct, while a `p` tag doesn't.

When you have a `span` tag without a closing tag the browser will try to correct the code the best it can by adding a closing tag at the last place where it could be. (There could be variantions between browsers and document modes, though.)

When you have a `p` tag without a closing tag, the paragraph is defined to end where the next block tag starts.

Comment: To further backup what Guffa is saying see here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html